# “Insufficient Permission” error when trying to get labels from GMail account using application-default credentials

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, gmail, credentials

I’m trying to run a node.js program that retrieves the labels from my GMail account. The build instructions (so you can see what I did) and code are here : https://github.com/chrisxkeith/gcp-js-credential-test .

After reading https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#strategies , it seemed to me that using application-default credentials was the best (e.g., simplest and most secure) way to go.

I’ve been able to use the application-default credentials to access the Cloud Storage service (https://github.com/chrisxkeith/gcp-js-credential-test/blob/main/test_cloud_storage.js ), but when I try to use the GMail service to retrieve the list of labels (https://github.com/chrisxkeith/gcp-js-credential-test/blob/main/test_get_email_labels.js ), I get an “Insufficient Permission” error.

How can I get past this error?

Comment: 2 questions: Is the service account authorized to access to the gmail account? On which product are you running your code? On Compute Engine?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere : 1) I looked through the settings on the service account, but don't see anywhere to give it access to GMail. Could you point me to some documentation about how to do this? 2) I'm just trying to get running this on my local machine. I have created a GCP project. If I get it working, I would create an App Engine to run it. Thanks!

Comment: @HonsaStunna: Is this better?

Comment: Does it a gmail address or a Google Workspace address?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere: Just logged in, and the Google Workspace logo shows up before getting to GMail.